# How to both filter and sort on ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: linq, sorting

I have this `IEnumerable<>`, but I cannot seem to find a way to both apply the `.Where()` and an `.OrderBy()`

```
ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(shipname) && (x.StartDate >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3) && x.StartDate <= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(3))).ToListAsync();
```

I want to apply an .OrderBy(), but how?

I tried ...

```
        ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(shipname) && (x.StartDate >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3) && x.StartDate <= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(3))),
.OrderBy() ..
```

I can't get it to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, the answer was staring me in the face ...

Break up the methods.

```
    ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules
        .Where(x => x.Text.Contains(shipname) && x.StartDate >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3) && x.StartDate <= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(3))
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
        .ToListAsync();
```